# Parse iOS in app purchase verification from Cloud Code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, in-app-purchase, verify

Since few days I'm trying to implement the iOS in-app purchase verification on the beforeSave of a purchase (on sandbox), but it always fail.
I tried the receipt with postman, and it works.

So, it's the Parse.Cloud.httpRequest the problem.

I tried also to put the receipt directly in the Cloud Code and it's always the same error (21002). https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Here is my code :

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url:'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt',
        body:{'receipt-data':receipt},
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            if (httpResponse.status == 0) {
                // success
            } else {
                // error
            }
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            // error
        }
    });
```

Is there someone that did it?

Answer (score 3):

If this a auto-renewal subscription?
If so, you missed the password field:

> password Only used for receipts that contain auto-renewable
>   subscriptions. Your app’s shared secret (a hexadecimal string).

in the jsonBody:

```
var jsonBody = {
                "receipt-data" : reference,
                "password" : "xxxxx"
            };
```

Also you should JSON encode the POST BODY (node example in the following)

```
itunes_client.post("", {}, JSON.stringify(jsonBody),
```

Comment: It's not a auto-renewable subscription. It's an consumable purchase. So I think there's no need a password. Do I need to put something in the headers?

Comment: I found this post. I did the same think with the param "body" but I'm still getting the error 21002.

Comment: @DavidGoncalvesdid you json stringify the body? That what I'm doing on node.js and it works. The error 21002 is on recepit validation error. Also keep a look at the json encoding on Parse: https://www.parse.com/questions/parsecloudhttprequest-problem-with-params

Comment: @DavidGoncalves Also, did you Base64 the receipt content? You have to.

Comment: Yes I Base64 the receipt. I tried it on postman and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much, JSON encoding the post body worked for me! Amazing!